# modifying the code in java classes on the server, as we do for jsp pages in vi editor

Tags: java, eclipse, war, putty, filezilla

My application requirement forces us to modify the code in the java classes frequently.
We are developing the java web application using using eclipse on tomcat server.

We develop and test our project on localhost. Once every thing is fine on localhost, we export the project as a war file and upload the war file through filezilla on our hosting server and using putty deploy the war file in webapps of tomcat and restart the tomcat for production (live).

After that if we find any thing to modify on the front end / UI side we connect to our hosting server through putty and go inside the project and modfiy the jsp page using vi editor.

But if we had to modify anything in java classes (say just a single line of additional code )then we upload the complete war file again which takes nearly 2 hours to upload because of the war file size.

My question is, is there any shortcut or alternative to modify the code in the java classes on the hosting server (not in local) without having the need to upload the complete war file again ?

Comment: No. As only the compiled version is there, also I would consider this practice a big no-go. Modifying files in production, next time you do a proper release, gone are your changes...

Comment: If it takes 2 hours to upload a simple war file, you should think about splitting up your application into modules. You could for example have separate jar files containing the modules. That way you could also exchange them easily.

Comment: if it takes 2 hours to upload your warfile, it's time to look for a better internet connection and/or a better hosting provider.

Comment: How do i split up application into modules.can you elaborate having separate jar files containing the modules. I export the project as a war file.